# Установка Rubyinstaller в Windows

Tags: ruby

Инсталирую последнею версию с сайта http://rubyinstaller.org/, но в при вводе команди git bash $ ruby --version, получаю ответ bash: ruby: command not found ?!

Comment: А в cmd всё нормально?

Comment: А вы добавили путь к бинарнику Ruby в переменную PATH?